# Humidifier not keeping up with HRV

Tags: furnace, humidifier

I just moved to an new (for us) house and we seem to not be able to keep the humidity up in the house. The house comes with a Heat Recovery Ventilator (HRV) that in the winter runs all the time on low speed with the Carrier Model 58MVB furnace running continually as well on low to move that new air around. The system is equipped with a General 1042 humidifier. Trying to get to 45% RH right now...outside temperature is 0 C or 32 F roughly.

It seems that the humidifier is only turning on when the furnace is in heat mode.  90% of the time the heating is off but we are drawing in dry outside air via the HRV and the humidifier is not running. So I suspect the wiring for the humidifier solenoid (it's a bypass humidifier) is possibly off of the heat mode terminals rather than the fan blower terminals.

I'm wondering if someone can tell me where they think the wires are connected right now and where they should be moved to?

I also have a Carrier SYSTXCCuid01-a Infinity control. From what I've read online it seems that the controller should be able to control the humidifier separately.  Step one is the wiring and step two is how to configure the controller.

I found a copy of he main control panel online:

[image]

The wiring from the humidifier solenoid valve is going to the HUM terminal and the COM 24V terminal.  Here are the photos.  The far left smaller white wire is attached to the HUM terminal which is staring back in the photo.  The adjoining red wire to the COM terminal.  These actual photos are taken from the left side of the control panel drawing above.

Red wire from solenoid to COM:
[image]

White wire from humidifier solenoid to HUM:
[image]

I also found some information on the Infinity Controller that states that it can initiate humidity addition even when there is no heat requirement. See Part 2 on the photo.

[image]